# Как правильно использовать оператор print

Tags: print, php

Доброго всем дня:

Возникло просто сомнение, так как всё работает. Но червь сомнения забрался в мой мозг и точит мой разум. Как всё-таки правильнее или это идентично до абсолюта?
Пример №1:

```
<?php
print $content;
print $content_continue;
?>
```

Пример №2

```
<?php print $content.$content_continue; ?>
```

---

Так как всё-таки вернее и правильнее? По примеру №1 или по примеру №2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соглашусь с предыдущим ответом и дополню.

Все зависит от логического контекса применения. Например, вам надо вывести таблицу и явно это будет удобнее, нагляднее (для дальнейшей разработки) и масштабируемо, когда вы пишете так:

```
print "<table>";
print "<tr>";
print "<td>";
print $cellData;
print "</td>";
print "</tr>";
print "</table>";
```

нежели, чем так:

```
print "<table><tr><td>" . $cellData . "</td></tr></table>";
```

На заметку, echo работает быстрее, чем print. Что касается самого echo, то он позволяет делать вывод через запятую, и если вам критична скорость выполнения скрипта, то этот вариант:

```
echo $content, $content_continue;
```

будет быстрее этого:

```
echo $content . $content_continue;
```

Но выиграете вы считанные миллисекунды, если объем данных не велик. Подведя итог можно сказать:

1. Если важна скорость - избавьтесь
       от конкатенации, где это возможно
2. Если нужна чистота и где возможно
       использовать конкатенацию -
       используйте
3. При выводе каких-то
       структурированных данных, лучше
       использовать несколько print/echo,
       для удобства дальнейшего поддержания
       кода

Comment: уже сколько копий сломано на дискуссии echo vs print, а тут ещё один.

Comment: Целью ответа не было разжение нового холивара, в итогах я даже не упомянул эту особенность, т.к. скорость в действительности не значительная и в большей степени зависит от ситуации

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю все правильно. Вопрос в том:"Какой тебе нравится"?)
А если по делу, то второй можно использовать для сокращения строчек в коде(компактность) а первый - для его удобного поиска в коде.
Короче сам смотри)